# How would I know if my SSD is compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, compatibility

Motherboard - Gigabyte B360M Gaming HD

SSD - Kingston 500GB A2000 M.2 2280 Nvme Internal SSD PCIe

Comment: There are steps in the manual on page 16 for installing an M.2 SSD.  This is for a B360 D3H but it might work for you.  https://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_b360m-d3h(gsm)_1002_e.pdf

Answer (score 0):

By reading the specifications: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B360M-GAMING-HD-rev-10/sp#sp it shows that the M.2 socket supports PCIe and SATA M.2 disks:

> M.2 connector (Socket 3, M key, type 2242/2260/2280 SATA and PCIe x4/x2 SSD support)

NVMe is the protocol for PCIe SSDs, which use M.2 key M form factor. Wireless cards use key E. Therefore the selected SSD should work on your board.